# run any sql command in jdbc java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to make SQL tool with java, I tried first to check command is true or false then as explained in pic

now i want to execute in command and  if it updates in database return number of rows update and if it selects rows should return ResultSet

```
 public Object run(String command){
 Boolean flag: runAnyCommand(command);
 Object data=nu11;
 if(f1ag){
 System.out.print1n(“trueeeeeeeeeeee”);

try {
Object s= st.execute(command);

if(s instanceof ResultSet ){

data=(ResultSet) s;
System.out.println(“result set ”);
}

else if(s instanceof Integer){

data=s;
 System.out.print1n(“update ant the rows is “+S);
  }

  } catch (SOLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(dbOperations.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, hull,     ex);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image contains method that i called it in servlet as example it returns object (boolean in case of update or arraylist in case of selection)

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shown us is incorrect.  The (JDBC) `Statement.execute` method returns a `boolean`, not an `Object`.  When you assign it to `Object`, that autoboxes it as a `Boolean`.  Therefore the code where you try to get a `ResultSet` or a `Integer` will never be executed.

If you want to obtain the `ResultSet` or the update count for an SQL statement executed with `execute(String)`, you should call `getResultSet()` or `getUpdateCount()` on the `Statement` object.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) for `Statement.execute(String)` provides more details, and offers links to the above methods.

Comment: thank you it solved and i uploaded the code in github https://github.com/ShiboTanany/SQLTool